# period in generated url instead of forward slash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am getting a weird state in my apps routes.

It's a basic discussion forum I am building with rails. I am using nested resources like:

```
 resources :forums do
  resources :discussions
 end
```

and generating a view to display all discussions with the requirement that clicking on any of these discussions should route to the appropriate discussion such as "forum/2/discussions/3". Yet when I use:

```
<% Discussion.find_each do |discussion| %>
 <%= link_to discussion.title, forum_discussions_path(discussion.forum_id, discussion) %>
<% end %>
```

the generated url/link is "forums/2/discussion.3" Any ideas why there is a "." instead of a "/"?

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. The Rails Guides are no help for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `forum_discussion` route, not the `forum_discussions` route

```
forum_discussion GET /forums/:forum_id/discussions/:id(.:format) discussions#show
```

Altogether that looks like

```
<% Discussion.find_each do |discussion| %>
  <%= link_to discussion.title, forum_discussion_path(discussion.forum_id, discussion) %>
<% end %>
```

---

You were pointing it to this route

```
forum_discussions GET /forums/:forum_id/discussions(.:format) discussions#index
```

so the `discussion.id` value was being used as the `:format` option.

Comment: You beauty! Thank you!! A shame the rails guide was no help with this.

Comment: Awesome! I so needed this.